# Accessing DOM elements via Automation scripts

Tags: maximo

Below was a case that I was working on that I solved with a launch in context, but I’m still wondering if there is a specific Maximo library that can help me access the DOM via automation script.

I’m looking for functionality similar to how Selenium works with their @browser tag. This tag lets a script reference elements in the current browser.

---

I'm looking to use an automation script, either JavaScript or Python syntax, in order to manipulate the DOM of the current application a user is on. What I'm trying to do is set the description tag of a current element, given the element ID, and I'm having trouble finding a package that can reference DOM elements.

I did some research on the psdi.common.context.UIContext package, but this was a pretty shallow package and did not provide the functionality I was looking for.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish in Maximo (which app, which object)? There are often multiple ways to meet a certain requirement. Some are more straightforward than others.

Comment: @JPTremblay that current case was solved, but I’m still curious if there are libraries that I can access via automation scripts that will allow me to manipulate the DOM. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: It seems that version 7.6.1.1 now allows you to access the WebClientSession object from the UIContext: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56706693/how-to-access-the-maximo-list-where-clause-programatically

Comment: Given that automation scripts are intended to run on the server side and be used to augment business logic without respect to presentation or any other particular interface, you will have a big job on your hands trying to couple what IBM has done a good job of decoupling.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I solved my issue by using Custom JSP components. I was able to create a .jsp page component with my code and embed it in the asset XML itself. I didn't know about this before, and it's pretty cool to see what types of customizations you can accomplish with custom JSP components. Reference link: http://vietmaximo.blogspot.com/2018/03/maximo-custom-control-part-iv-create.html