# How to call an action menu or toolbar button from automation script in Maximo

Tags: maximo

I am trying to call a button in the more actions tab of an application from my automation script. Does anyone know what method to call to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to do what you ask, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58491400/5368626) to another question will get you heading in the right direction. You'll need to know the name of the event / method to call, and you may find `psdi.webclient.system.beans.DataBean.findAndCallMethod()` useful.

But it is often the case that the event / method behind such buttons just calls on other server-side logic. So, you might be working harder rather than smarter by trying to do this. It might be smarter to look in the Maximo JavaDocs for the class on the object you're working with for a method that sounds like what you want to do. Or look on the service the database object is in. (You can find the classes for the objects and services in Database Configuration.)

If someone knows better, I'm happy to hear from them.

Comment: I am trying to call the button to access the context it is in. I need a set that's in an application to fetch the selected records in the set. I've tried to use a relationship but it does not fetch the set in the context so I can't view the selected records.

Comment: In that case, if the link I provided about accessing the MboSet for the List tab isn't good enough, then you need to provide a [example] demonstrating the problem in order to get better help from us (SO).